# SFSafariViewController safariViewControllerDidFinish

Tags: ios9

I'm confused about the use of the `SFSafariViewController` delegate method `safariViewControllerDidFinish:`. The docs and tutorials say I need to use this to close my view when the user selects 'Done'.  But it works (closing the view) just fine without implementing the delegate method.

Am I missing something, do I need to implement it anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to implement it.

> When Done is tapped in a SFSafariViewController, it is automatically dismissed. You no longer need to dismiss it in the delegate method safariViewControllerDidFinish:.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/